# Decrypt a video part by part, and stream it through video player

Tags: android, video, encryption

Ok, I have a video encrypted through AES, stored in the internal memory of an Android powered device. What i want is that the video should only be played through an android app.

It would be appreciated if that application would decrypt the video part by part, store it in a virtual memory, and then stream it.

My question:

1. Is it possible to decrypt it part by part and stream?

If Yes, what would be the basic process?

If No, (nothing is impossible to code)

2. To make it happen, do i need to design my own video player android app, or can i use some existing app to work inside my app?

Answer (score 0):

This subject is already treated in many questions.
For instance, look at [How to play an encrypted video file in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193350/how-to-play-an-encrypted-video-file-in-android)